# Android Studio 1.0.2 Kickflip.io ShortTypeHandling Error

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle

I am trying to test out the android example of kickflip.io github repo (https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-example), but once I've imported the example I am getting the following error: `Cause: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling`

Using Android Studio 1.0.2 and Gradle 2.2.1

Below you will see my gradle files.

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
```

gradle wrapper:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
```

'

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
    classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'io.kickflip:sdk:1.1.1'
}
```

Error Log pertaining to `Cause: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getLocalVersion(BasePlugin.groovy:3612)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.<init>(BasePlugin.groovy:258)
at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.<init>(AppPlugin.groovy:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:67)
... 73 more'
```

Comment: The actual exception stacktrace might help

Answer (score 5):

Change the line

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
```

from your gradle-wrapper.properties file to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip
```

This helped in my case

Comment: Just to add some context, the line to change is in `gradle-wrapper.properties` (eg. MyProject/gradle/wrapper/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong gradle version.  If your IDE actually picked up the gradle version from the wrapper (1.10), then above mentioned class would not have been in the groovy version.  The class was introduced in Groovy 2.3.

Use the same version of gradle as indicated by the version of the android plugin, which is 2.2.1 (or at least to 2.1.X IIRC, this is the first one to use Groovy 2.3).  Maybe you just have to change to a fixed version in IntelliJ instead of choosing the "custom wrapper" flag.

Answer (score 0):

This project's original [build.gradle](https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-example/blob/master/build.gradle) file says :

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
```

Try changing the value to 1.0 because many projects support the 1.0 stable version of the gradle. Good luck.